# How to correct import JS file to another JS file and then to index.html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

Hello i have following problem. I have 3 files. `Main.js`, `variable.js`, `index.html`

For this demonstation of problem i will be simple as much as i can be..

**variable.js**

```
const sayHello = () => {
  return "sayHello";
};

export { sayHello };
```

**main.js**

```
import { sayHello } from "./Vari";

console.log(sayHello);
```

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I watched several tutorials on Youtube checked several text tutorials on google but i'm lost. Im no getting any console error, im getting nothing. I can see only blank window. I'm newbie sont bite me please. Ive installed node.js and in the folder i have package.json with Following informations:

```
{
  "name": "doucovanispetrem-priklady",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Johny Inkognito",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your main sayHello function should be executed, so it can have effect on index.html

In main.js you import sayHello function, but you don't execute it.

And the file name where you declare the sayHello function is variables.js not Vari.

Another important note looking to your package.json, you are not using any kind of bundler like webpack for example, this is why the main.js file will not be able to import variable module without prefix.

Comment: ou sorry that was my misstake. vari = variables but somehow the issue was that it had to be variables.js not just variables. If you can explain why it matter it would be great pls cuz the import line was generated by VSC so i trusted to IDE

Comment: update your question with everything in your package.json

Comment: Package.json is updated ^^

Comment: It is normal, you are not using any bundler like webpack for example, bundlers can resolve imports without prefix, but a native HTML file can't do that, and by the way, your main is main.js not index.html

Comment: main was only the example for this demonstration. My main is index ;)